# Should I use string object for function parameters?

Tags: autohotkey

Here is function to stop any running process:

```
ProcessStop(process_name) {
    Run, %ComSpec% /k taskkill -f -im %process_name%.exe -t
}
```

And now I could call it:

```
ProcessStop("autohotkey") ; Any running AHK scripts will be stopped
```

I'm novice in AHK and I want to know, is it good enough to use quotes in function call or is it better to avoid them (and how?)

```
; This:
ProcessStop("autohotkey")

; vs. this:
ProcessStop(autohotkey)
```

What is better? (And if second variant is better, how I could make it work?)

Comment: Ofcourse why not! are you getting an error?

Comment: @MurhafSousli You mean, I should use quotes, right? :)

Comment: yes, it is called string object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ProcessStop(autohotkey)` unless you define `autohotkey`

`ProcessStop("autohotkey")` Should do the job

If you have certain options for the parameter, a better approach that increases your code readability is to define an enum or just an object like this

```
const ProcessOptions = {
    AUTOHOTKEY: 'AUTOHOTKEY',
    ANOTHER_OPTION: 'ANOTHER_OPTION'
}
```

then you can use it like so

```
ProcessStop(ProcessOptions.AUTOHOTKEY)
```